# string displacement function by d'Alembert's formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider an infinite string stretched taut on $x$ axis from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ . Let the string be drawn aside into a curve $y=f(x)$ and released, and assume that its subsequent motion is described by the wave equation.

Use

$$y(x, t) = F(x + at) + G(x − at)$$

to show that the string’s displacement is given by d’Alembert’s formula :

$$y(x, t) = \frac{f(x + at) + f(x − at)}{2}$$

I have this problem from Simmons Differential Equations book, but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: Use your initial condition that $y(x,0) = f(x)$ (you should also have been given $y_t(x,0) = 0$) and solve the two equations to get $y(x,t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

$$y(x,t) = F(x + at) + G(x - at)$$

We have that

$$\begin{align} \\
y(x,0) &= f(x) \\
&= F(x) + G(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
\end{align}$$

You should also have another condition that

$$\begin{align} \\
\partial_t y(x,0) &= 0 \\
&=  aF'(x) - aG'(x) \\
\implies F'(x) &= G'(x) \\
\implies F(x) &= G(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)\\
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$

$$\begin{align} \\
\implies f(x) &= F(x) + F(x) \\
&= 2F(x) \\
\implies \frac{1}{2}f(x) &= F(x) \\
\end{align}$$

But we also have

$$\begin{align} \\
f(x) &= G(x) + G(x) \\
&= 2G(x) \\
\implies \frac{1}{2}f(x) &= G(x) \\
\end{align}$$

Hence

$$\begin{align} \\
y(x,t) &= F(x + at) + G(x - at) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}f(x + at) + \frac{1}{2}f(x - at) \\
&= \frac{f(x + at) + f(x - at)}{2} \\
\end{align}$$